# How can I check a radio button on load, based on it's value?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I've got the value of a radio button (r1) and I'm trying to use:

> $("input:radio[val=r1]").attr('checked', true);

to check it.

The thing is that I've got three radio buttons in a div,
when I check one, the value of the checked button gets stored.

When I reload the page I want the page to check the radio button that was chosen last.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute is called `value`.  Try:

```
$('input:radio[value=r1]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

To uncheck you would call:

```
$(selector).removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected radio button is not natively preserved over the postbacks. It all depends on the server-side language that you use to restore the state i.e. check the respective radio button.